# Android: Is there another way to display data from a string array?

Tags: android, textview, arrays

I am trying to display the steps to a recipe, the recipe is stored in a string array.

Im trying to get each step to be inserted into a text view, and have the following code:

```
public class MethodActivity extends ListActivity{

ListView recipes;
Intent myIntent;
String value;
TextView editvalue;
Intent intent;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  


    setContentView(R.layout.recipemethod);

    editvalue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.method);
    value = getIntent().getStringExtra("searchValue");
    editvalue.setText(value);

    final String[]  words = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Lasagna);
    final TextView tw=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.method);
    for(int item = 0;item<words.length;item++){
        tw.setText(words [item]);
    }
  }
}
```

I am also wanting to make it dynamic so does anyone know how I can do that? (e.g. depending on what the user clicked that recipe is shown).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easier to actually use your `ListActivity`'s `ListView`... You can even show your recipe in another `ListView`, as it will undoubtedly be more intuitive for the user...

A simple code that does this would go somewhat in the following lines:

File 1: RecipeListActivity.java (shows list of recipes)

```
package com.epichorns.testproject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class RecipeListActivity extends ListActivity {

    final Recipe[] mRecipesArray = {    new Recipe("Lasagna", new String[]{"Some lasagna noodles", "Some tomato sauce"}),
                                        new Recipe("PortalCake", new String[]{"GlaDOS' wit","Is a lie"}),
                                        new Recipe("EarthDestruction", new String[]{"Asteroid", "Kinetic energy"})};


    public class Recipe{
        public String name;
        public String[] steps;

        Recipe(String name, String[] steps){
            this.name = name;
            this.steps = steps;
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<String> FetchRecipesRawArray(Recipe[] recipes){
        ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0;i<recipes.length;i++){
            ret.add(recipes[i].name);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FetchRecipesRawArray(mRecipesArray));
        setListAdapter(adapter); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RecipeActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(RecipeActivity.EXTRA_RECIPEARRAY, mRecipesArray[position].steps);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

File 2: RecipeActivity.java (shows a recipe in a list)

```
package com.epichorns.testproject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;


public class RecipeActivity extends ListActivity {
    final static public String EXTRA_RECIPEARRAY = "recipeArray";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  

        String[] recipeArray = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra(EXTRA_RECIPEARRAY);
        if(recipeArray!=null){
            if(recipeArray.length>0){
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, recipeArray);
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Alternately, here is a code which composites a TextView below the recipes list in order to show the recipe content without opening another Activity:

File: RecipeListActivity.java

```
package com.epichorns.testproject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class RecipeListActivity extends ListActivity {

    final Recipe[] mRecipesArray = {    new Recipe("Lasagna", new String[]{"Some lasagna noodles", "Some tomato sauce"}),
                                        new Recipe("PortalCake", new String[]{"GlaDOS' wit","Is a lie"}),
                                        new Recipe("EarthDestruction", new String[]{"Asteroid", "Kinetic energy"})};

    TextView mTextView_recipeTitle;
    TextView mTextView_recipe;


    public class Recipe{
        public String name;
        public String[] steps;

        Recipe(String name, String[] steps){
            this.name = name;
            this.steps = steps;
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<String> FetchRecipesRawArray(Recipe[] recipes){
        ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0;i<recipes.length;i++){
            ret.add(recipes[i].name);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mTextView_recipe = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.recipeText);
        mTextView_recipeTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.recipeTitle);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FetchRecipesRawArray(mRecipesArray));
        setListAdapter(adapter); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){

        mTextView_recipeTitle.setText(mRecipesArray[position].name);

        mTextView_recipe.setText("");

        String[] recipeSteps = mRecipesArray[position].steps;
        for(int i=0;i<recipeSteps.length;i++){
            mTextView_recipe.append(recipeSteps[i]+"\n");
        }

    }
}
```

File: main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#400000FF"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recipeTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#4000FF00"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recipeText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#40FF0000"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It does not like     setListAdapter(adapter), any idea why this might be?

Comment: Did you copy the code verbatim? It compiled fine on my HTC Desire device (remember to declare all your activities in your AndroidManifest.xml). Note: I will also provide you with an alternate code base, where the list is on top, and a textview on the bottom, like you envisioned originally... See below my first answer.

Comment: Just testing it out but I believe the error was simply because I didnt extend ListActivity. Silly me. Will let you know how it turns out :)

Comment: Thanks that is working now, only question I have is If I have a string array in the strings XML how can I access that for the recipe to be retrived? and is hard coding the recipes array a safe thing to do? Not saying its wrong. lol

Comment: Well, if your string array name is, say... `recipes_array`, then you would retrieve it like this: `String[] tmpArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.recipes_array);` As of hardcoding your recipes, of course it is doable and safe. The question is: what is the use of such an application where all recipes are hardcoded? From my standpoint, wouldn't it be better if you store your stuff in some kind of database, with an interface so that the user can add custom recipes to it?

Comment: That was the original intentions for this application but I simply ranout of time, I tried that but how would the new recipe access it? Like this:  new Recipe("Lasagna", tmpArray)

Comment: Would this way work if I wanted to only display certain recipes in the list? So say the user types a recipe only the recipes with that in the name are returned?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use tw.append() instead of setText, otherwise all you will ever see is the last string in the array.

Make it dynamic, I would use a fragments (using the Android Support Library if on older android versions) model, load each array, attaching the string array as a bundle to the fragment before launching.

Fragment tut:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html
 Support library: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/support-lib.html