# How to DISPLAY an array of strings on android

Tags: android

I want nothing but my app to display the strings on the main activity, all that happens when the app opens is the array of strings is displayed. Nothing more nothing less. Can not seem to find this information anywhere!

Comment: How do you want it to look? as a gridView or each string in a new row? 
What have you tried?

Comment: `Can not seem to find this information anywhere!` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402428/android-is-there-another-way-to-display-data-from-a-string-array

Comment: You looked?  Really? http://bit.ly/12Zxam6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a textview to the main activity, then make a object of the textview like this.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_of_text_view);
```

Then set text to the textview like this:

```
textView.setText("blah");
```

Get the text from where ever you stored it

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you wanted to display them in a ListView, use an ArrayAdapter and add the strings to the adapter.

Btw, if the array is in your string resources, use getResources().getStringArray(R.array.id) to get the array from your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ListView component.

list_cars.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp" >
</TextView>


public class ListCarsActivity extends ListActivity {

static final String[] CARS = new String[] { "BWM", "Volvo", "Mersedes-Benz",
        "Honda", "Toyota", "Nexia", "Wolkswagen", "CHevrolet",
        "Ferrari", "Volga", "Porshe", "Bentley", "Bugatti" };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //  it is not needed
    // setContentView(R.layout.list_cars);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_cars,CARS));

    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

}